# How can this equation be simplified this way? Transmission line: Zin

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I thought of putting this on the Electrical Engineering Exchange but I thought since this seems more mathematical than related to engineering I thought I should place it here instead.

Question: Why for a quarter wave transformer does the equation for Zin of a lossless tranformer simplify to the following equation:

$$ Z_{in} = \frac{(Z_o)^2}{Z_L} $$

Usually the equation is:

$$ Z_{in} = Z_o \left[ \frac{Z_L + Z_o i tan(\beta l)}{Z_o + Z_L i tan(\beta l)}\right] $$

Where $i$ is the imaginary unit, $\beta = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and $l = \frac{\lambda}{4}$ So putting those values for $\beta$ and $\lambda$ we get the following equation:

$$ Z_{in} = Z_o \left[ \frac{Z_L + Z_o i tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}{Z_o + Z_L i tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}\right] $$

Now my question how do I get from the above equation to:

$$ Z_{in} = \frac{(Z_o)^2}{Z_L} $$

I know $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty$ so how can I simplify? My book just assumes I know how to get there. Is there some relationship that I don't know or have forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z_L$ and $Z_0$ are non-zero:

$$
\begin{align}
Z_{in} &= Z_0 \left( \frac{Z_L + Z_0 i \tan(\pi/2)}{Z_0 + Z_L i \tan(\pi/2)}\right)\\
&= Z_0 \left( \frac{\dfrac{Z_L}{\tan(\pi/2)} + Z_0 i }{\dfrac{Z_0}{\tan(\pi/2)} + Z_L i}\right)\\
&= Z_0 \left( \frac{0 + Z_0 i }{0 + Z_L i}\right)\\
&=  \frac{(Z_0)^2  }{ Z_L }
\end{align}
$$

Above $\tan(\pi/2)$ is an abuse of notation in mathematics. I assume $\dfrac{c}{\tan(\pi/2)}=0$ for any non-zero $c$, since you use $\tan(\pi/2)$ in your equations freely.

Comment: Alistair, thank you very much. I have some questions though. If tan(pi/2) is an abuse of notation, what is the correct one? Also, I agree with your algebraic manipulation, but how did you know how to do that or when proving anything goes as long as it's mathematically sound. I have trouble with that sometimes if it's okay to do something like that.

Comment: @TwilightSparkleTheGeek. If you're given an equation like this $\frac{Z_L + Z_0 i \tan(\pi/2)}{Z_0 + Z_L i \tan(\pi/2)}$, then they want from you is interpret $\tan(\pi/2)$ to be "a very big number". That means it's probably okay to them to divide with this infinitely big number. Correct way to write this is $\lim_{\theta\to \pi/2}\frac{Z_L + Z_0 i \tan\theta}{Z_0 + Z_L i \tan\theta}$. You probably make less mistakes if you see infinities in your equations as limit of a function depending on some parameter that's going to infinity, like above.

Comment: Oh, okay I see, I remember my calculus teacher saying something about that, how to intuitively go about it. Thanks. I'll write it like that as you said to avoid mistakes.